# Read BLE Beacons from react PWA

Tags: reactjs, bluetooth-lowenergy, positioning, progressive-web-apps, beacon

I'm designing a PWA for customer support.
One of the functionalities will require precisely (5 meters error margin) positioning the user's phone.
I'm thinking of using beacons as their range and precision suites my needs.

the thing is: How can I read beacons from a react.js (no native) PWA? Of course for triangulation, this would require reading several beacons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sorry, there is no practical way to make a web app that scans for bluetooth beacons due to the lack of browsers' support for bindings to raw bluetooth scanning.**

Google Chrome does support BLE interaction via JavaScript through the [Web Bluetooth API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/interact-with-ble-devices-on-the-web).  However, it only supports discovering and connecting to GATT services, not arbitrary BLE scanning needed to find beacons.  This means you cannot find iBeacon, Eddystone or AltBeacon compatible devices.

You might be able to discover a connectable custom BLE device that simulates beacon behavior through a connectable GATT service.  But even if you did this, it would only work on Chrome, not on Safari, Microsoft or Firefox browsers, because Web Bluetooth is not supported on those platforms.

Even if you get this working on Chrome with a custom beacon, bluetooth beacons only provide very rough distance estimates.  Triangulation only works decently at very close ranges of 3 meters or less.  More practical indoor positioning techniques with beacons use RSSI fingerprinting not triangulation.  And again, even Google Chrome with Web Bluetooth does not support the arbitrary scanning needed to do this.